How can I get Intellisense working when importing my own npm package?
I have some confusion here. I have a project which just returns some types and a react component, it is published to npm. I have set my tsconfig file as so:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "ES6",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["./index.d.ts", "src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.types.ts"]
}

I have set the following values in my package.json:
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "types": "build/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "build",
    "LICENSE"
  ],
...
  "scripts": {
...
    "build": "rm -rf build && tsc && cp index.d.ts ./build && cp index.js ./build",
  },

and index.d.ts
...

declare function PictureImage(props: PictureImageProps): JSX.Element;

When I install the package in my consuming project, it all appears to work but I have no intellisense. Can anyone advise? The complete library is here https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-picture-image and it is a public repo.
I've tried both automatically generating the index.d.ts and manually creating it but neither makes a difference.


What kind of intellisense you expect?

build/index.js doesn't exist

Works fine here. import { PictureImage } from 'next-picture-image'. Hovering PictureImage gives what you would expect.
